# MySQL Cursors fetching null value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

Data fetched from cursor is NULL. But number of row my query `select id from Projects` returning is correct. I have put a select statement in my procedure loop to debug. It's returning null for id.
I have followed this [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html]
What's wrong with this code?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ReportDiffProDiffFinYear`()
BEGIN

DECLARE id INT;
DECLARE sqlstr varchar(10000) default "select financialYear as 'name' "; 
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select id from Projects; /* My CURSOR QUERY*/
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


 OPEN cur1;

 read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO id;
  select id;
  IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;
  set sqlstr = concat(sqlstr, ", sum(if(projects_id=",id,",0,1)) ");
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
   set @sqlstr = concat(sqlstr," from (select * from WaterPoints  where status='Waterpoint Complete') as wp, (select id,financialYear from ProjectDetails) as pd where pd.id=wp.projectDetails_id group by  pd.financialYear");

 prepare stmt from @sqlstr;
 execute stmt;
 deallocate prepare stmt;
 END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your variable name `id` clashes with the query for the cursor, therefore the cursor query fetches the value of the `id` variable (null), not the value of the id from the `projects` table. Either change the name of the variable or use `projects.id` to reference the column in the query.